# You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, mysql-error-1064

My code is so far

```
        $limitText ="";
        if($history_length){
            $limitText = ' limit '. $history_length;
        }

        if(!$history_days){
            $history_days = '180';
        }
$db = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter();
        //changing code to add min(currBalance) -- as sum(points) is valid only for debit. Also sort by desc instead of  (major bug)
        $history_stmt = $db->query("SELECT sum(points) as points,credit_date,min(currBalance) as currBalance,extRefId,transactedAt,pointType FROM credits where userid = '".$userid."' and credit_date >= date('now','-".$history_days." days')  group by extRefID,pointType order by creditid desc ".$limitText);
        $history_results = $history_stmt->fetchall();

        $expiry_stmt = $db->query("SELECT availablePoints,expiry_date FROM credits where userid = '".$userid."'and availablePoints > 0 and expiry_date <= date('now','+".$expiry_duration." days') order by expiry_date asc ");
        $expiry_results = $expiry_stmt->fetchall();
```

I got an error

```
<b>Message:</b> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''-180 days')  group by extRefID,pointType order by creditid desc' at line 1  </p>
```

what i can do I am not able to fine the solution

Comment: what u want to do exactly?? use `DATEDIFF` or `DATE_ADD`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you are using the [MySQL Date function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) in a wrong way - were you actually planning on using the [php date](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function instead? Instead of e.g.

```
"[...] credit_date >= date('now','-".$history_days." days')  group by [...]"
```

you'd have to write:

```
 "[...] credit_date >= '".date('-'.$history_days.' days')."' group by [...]"
```

Only variables (e.g. $history_days) will get expanded by php in a string enclosed with double quotes ("), but not function calls. If you enclose a function call inside the string, php can't recognize it, and it will be passed as is to mysql, instead of first being executed by php; but you want php to evaluate it, so you'll have to exclude it from the string constant and add it with the concatenation operators (.) to your string.

Your php date function call however also seems to be incorrect; to get "the current date minus a certain amount of days", best use mysql date functions like this:

```
 "[...] credit_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL '$history_days' DAY) group by [...]"
```

And just one general note on security: It's not clear from the piece of script you're providing, but if the values in `$history_days`, `$history_length`, `$user_id` or `$expiry_duration` (the variables used inside the SQL statement) have only the remotest chance of being set by the user, you should not insert them directly into an SQL statement, but [do something to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).